# return highest value of lists

Tags: python, list

Hello I have a few lists and im trying to create a new list of the highest values repsectively. for an example, these are the lists:

```
list1 = 5, 1, 4, 3
list2 = 3, 4, 2, 1
list3 = 10, 2, 5, 4
```

this is what I would like it to return:

```
[10, 4, 5, 4]
```

I thought that I could do a something like this:

```
largest = list(map(max(list1, list2, list3)))
```

but I get an error that map requires more than 1 argument.

I also thought I could write if, elif statements for greater than but it seems like it only does the first values and returns that list as the "greater value"

thanks for any help

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is the "zip splat" trick:

```
>>> lists = [list1, list2, list3]
>>> [max(col) for col in zip(*lists)]
[10, 4, 5, 4]
```

You could also use numpy arrays:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> np.array(lists).max(axis=0)
array([10,  4,  5,  4])
```

Comment: that worked, thank you very much. in uncertain terms I understand why this works, again I appreciate the help!

Answer (score 6):

You have used `map` incorrectly. Replace that last line with this:

```
largest = list(map(max, zip(list1, list2, list3)))
```

In `map`, the first argument is the function to be applied, and the second argument is an iterable which will yield elements to apply the function on. The `zip` function lets you iterate over multiple iterables at once, returning tuples of corresponding elements. So that's how this code works!

Comment: Ohh, ok thank you, this makes total sense. I was using map to do subtraction of values from a list, I duplicated the line, deleted the sub and replaced it with the list variables. kicking myself. Thank you for the help, it will be useful in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Using `map`'s iterable**S** argument has an implicit `zip`-like effects on the iterables.

```
map(max, *(list1, list2, list3))
```